#  Is there a UL listed relay for a line voltage device?

Tags: electrical, product-recommendation

I once saw a device with full UL listing that was effectively a relay that could switch on or off a line voltage device. It looked something like a short extension cord but then had a low voltage wire coming off of it to control the setup.

Does anyone know about anything like this? I want to build a few DIY electronics projects but for insurance reasons I need the UL certification.

Answer (score 1):

I once saw the [PowerSwitch Tail](http://powerswitchtail.com/), which is functionally what you describe, but does not indicate that it is UL listed.